# How to create a Yii2 Html form and Action

Tags: yii2

I want to create a basic yii2 html with controller action just like below

```
<?= \yii\helpers\Html::beginForm('index.php?r=userprofile/changeusername','post') ?>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputsm">Change Username</label>
                                    <?= Html::textInput('username'); ?>
                                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-theme">Change</button>
                                    <?= Html::button('Press me!', ['class' => 'submit']) ?>
                                  </div>
                                  <?= \yii\helpers\Html::endForm() ?>
```

How to make a controller action for this

Answer (score 0):

It's best to go to the `WEB` file and configure the **Gii** tool. (Or check).The Guide to GII: This [link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-gii) or in on this [Page](https://yii2-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tool-gii/).

Then go to [localhost/gii](http://localhost/path/to/index.php?r=gii) at localhost. or example.com/gii

if you have enabled pretty URLs, tutorial on this [link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii)

You can easily create models, form, controller and even CRUD and.. with Gii in yii2.

> Yii includes a handy tool, named Gii, that provides rapid prototyping by generating commonly used code snippets as well as complete CRUD controllers.
>   Gii provides a Web-based interface for you to interactively generate the code you want. It also provides a command line interface for people who prefer to work with their console windows most of the time.

**Controller for your view:**

```
use Yii;

class UserprofileController extends yii\web\Controller
{
  # code...

  public function actionChangeusername()
  {
    # code...

    if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
        # code...
        return $this->redirect('path/...');  // sample ...
     }

     return $this->render('index', [
         'param' => $var,  /* sample: Access to variables in the view ... */
     ]);
  }
//...

}
```

If you want to validate the form (via model ..), you should use `activeTextInput`

Also read about the following classes and widgets: 
[`Model`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models), [`ActiveRecord`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record), [`ActiveForm`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-forms) , [`ActiveFiel`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield)

 [Validation rules](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators) ([Adhoc](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#ad-hoc-validation) ,[Validating Input](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#validating-input)....)